# xampp version 1.7.4 to configure oracle 12c instance client but not connecting.

Tags: php, xampp, oracle12c

I have xampp version 1.7.4 in which my PHP Version 5.3.5 . I am trying to configure oracle 12c instance client but not connecting. Please provide which version of php will support oracle 12c